# Very light overlay-ish home screen

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, home-screen

Is there a homescreen that will basically pop up when I hit home, and I can go right back to what I was doing with the return softkey? It can require root, as I have that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found TaskXP for MultiTasking which someone recommended. It's just what I wanted. It shows my recent apps and any apps that I pin, in an overlay that I can quickly hit back from.

Answer (score 0):

You could just press your home key to go to your home screen - do what you need to there, even open another app. Then just long-press the home key again to pop up the list of recently used apps and select the original app you were in to return to where you were.

Should work.